# Cannot install package --with-doc on Ubuntu : tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty: Cannot open: File exists

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, tlmgr

I cannot install a TeX Live package `--with-doc` on Ubuntu :

```
$ tlmgr list --only-installed 
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
$ tlmgr install --with-doc pdfpages
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final (verified)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: pdfpages [321k]
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppdvipdfmx.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppdvips.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppnull.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppvtex.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
untar: untarring /tmp/GXaZ1f0fBb/7RFaVvA_3t/pdfpages.tar failed (in /home/sebastien/texmf)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/sebastien/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your TeXLive distribution is quite old (2017). Maybe it tries to install the package into an area where there is already another tex distribution?

Comment: @gernot Yes, there is : `dpkg -s texlive-base | grep Version
Version: 2017.20180305-1` and the `pdfpages` package seems already installed by the `texlive-latex-recommended` package (also Version: 2017.20180305-1) in`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/`

Comment: Unless you have the need to experiment with an old version of (La)TeX, may I suggest that you remove the old installation and install a recent version? Investing any time into resolving a problem that may be specific to your combination of TeXLive 2017 and your OS seems wasted. Moreover, there will be hardly anyone here who can reconstruct the issue.

Comment: I agree with gernot, if your latex is coming from your Linux Dist, then it is unlikely there will be any updates for it. Also note that Linux dists have a tendency nowadays to alter `tlmgr` such that it can only be used to configure TeXLive, but not install packages (as the Linux dist wants you to do what via the Linux dists own package system). It might be an idea to manually install the upstream TeXLive 2020 instead (see tug.org/texlive)

Comment: @daleif If I uninstall the `texlive-base` Ubuntu package and re-install Tex Live manually, will I be able to install LaTex packages system-wide with `tlmgr` ?

Comment: If done right and you have the space, installing upsteam texlive will not need the uninstallation of `texlive-base`

Comment: @daleif According to the GUI of [install-tl](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz), the full install scheme will take 7099MB in `/usr/local/texlive/`, my `/usr/local` is not that big. I the meantime of growing it, I think I'll go for the small installation scheme :D (522MB) !

Comment: When using the upstream texlive you can always add extra schemes later. Since space is cheap I usually install it all

Comment: @daleif And to install an extra scheme, you can type `sudo tlmgr install scheme-THE_SCHEME_I_WANT_TO_INSTALL`, right ?

Comment: Something like that. I even might not install it as super user. Recently I've started installing the minimal scheme via the installer on Windows and then upgrade to scheme-full via tlmgr later. You can also use tlmgr to install individual packages